# Can't find AD user using the command get-aduser when the user is an object

Tags: powershell, window, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I have CSV file:

```
phone         username
--------      ---------
1               user1
2               user2
```

first I run:

```
$arr = import-csv "c:\names.csv"
```

so for example this is the output when I run:

```
 $arr[0].username 
user1
```

Now, my goal is to find this user in AD and when I run:

```
$user = get-aduser -filter {Name -eq $arr[0].username}
```

I received:

> Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq $arr[0].username' Error
>   Message: 'Operator Not supported: ' at position: '1 4'. At line:1
>   char:19
>   + $user = get-aduser <<<<  -filter {Name -eq $arr[0].username}
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq $arr[0].username' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported:
>       ' at position: '14'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

**But**, when I run:

```
$user = get-aduser -filter {Name -eq "user1"}
```

it works fine.

how can I find the users using `$arr[0].username` ? 
what is the difference ? both of them strings:
"user1" and `$arr[0].username` ...

Thanks,
for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the username to a variable and use it in the query:

```
$name = $arr[0].username
$user = get-aduser -filter {Name -eq $name}
```

or use an expanded string instead of a script block:

```
$user = get-aduser -filter "Name -eq '$($arr[0].username)'"
```

Comment: it works, tnx :)
I wonder what was the problem with just writing:
 $arr[0].username

why it didn't work? why I needed to change it to expanded string: '$($arr[0].username)'  ?

Comment: Script block is passed "as-is" and is evaluated on the server, using expandable strings makes sure the value is expanded on the client before it moves on to the server. That being said, I'm not sure why it fails.